# High chart how to process config if get config from DB and it contianed a function?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

let's say I got a chart configuration from the server-side :

```
  let chartConfig = {
    chart: {
      type: "bar"
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: `function () {
        return  this.point.name + ':' +this.y;
    }`
    },
  };
```

so the formatter function needs to be a string so it can be saved to be a JSON string.
and it will not work as a string.

I am using react with highchart-react-officail lib.

I tried this :

```
    useEffect(() => {
        chartConfig.tooltip.formatter = tooltipsFormat;
    }, [])

    const tooltipsFormat = () => {
        return this.key + '<br/>' 
    }
```

to reassign a function to formatter, but clearly, the 'this' here is not the same one with the one in the configuration.

what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        chartConfig.tooltip.formatter = function(){
           return this.key + '<br/>' 

    }, [])
```

will resolve the problem.